# Do you have better solutions for Sprite spawning like jetpack joyride cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

First of all I'm using cocos2d-x on android with c++ language.
I'm trying to make a game similar to jetpack joyride.The problem is that I didn't find an efficient way to spawn my obstacles. Here is the way I'm using :

I'm repeating endlessly this method but the game is really slow and sometimes it doesn't even start and my application crashes

```
void myClass::SpawnSprite(float dt){

// The sprites are moving with moveBy...

}
```

Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: I just want you please to understand what I'm trying to do, and provide me a better solution

Comment: #define PIPE_SPAWN_FREQUENCY 0.001 //0.0012  petit = rapide

  this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::SpawnPipe ), PIPE_SPAWN_FREQUENCY * visibleSize.width );

Comment: Please edit your post and include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this in my main class

```
#define PIPE_SPAWN_FREQUENCY 0.001 //0.0012  petit = rapide

  this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::SpawnPipe ), PIPE_SPAWN_FREQUENCY * visibleSize.width );


void myClass::SpawnSprite(float dt) {

  // The sprites are moving with moveBy...

}
```